# How to modify pan sensitivity in achartengine?

Tags: android, achartengine

It is a simple question. Is there any way to modify the pan sensitivity to move an XYChart? Move it faster or "accelerate" the movement to scroll through it rapidly.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pan works in a "natural" way. This means it moves as much as you drag on the screen. So, you cannot move it faster or slower.

Comment: Is any way to manually drag the chart? For example I want to view between 1000 and 1500 in X series.

Comment: Sure it is. renderer.setXAxisMin(), renderer.setXAxisMax(), similar for Y axis.